# How do you get files updated from a GIT repository in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I have successfully checked out a project from GIT hub but since then changes have been made to the repository. When I right click to team the PULL option is grayed out, when I fetch from upstream it says the files are up to date, but that is not true. I can verify this by visually comparing the file on my computer to the file at GIT hub.  Is there any way to resolve this problem other than switching back to subversion?

Answer (score 0):

You need to merge the fetch upstream into your branch to get the updated repository.

Or, you can use terminal

```
git pull origin master
```

Check this [git pull docs](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html)

Also, `Pull` option is graved out because egit requires the branches to be set up for pull for the option to be available.

Comment: The merge tool is also Grayed out

Comment: That happens in `Egit`, I've faced it and solved but I'm not certain how right now.
 In such scenario, I generally use git commands.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like I was able to partially resolve this using "rebase". But everything (pull/merge) is still grayed out so I'll take a look at the docs. When I did the checkout instead of home/git I put it in home/workspace so the repository and project are the same folder. I don't think this was the correct method of setup, but it is semi-functional.

Comment: `rebase` and `pull` are quite different, You can find related docs. Try restarting eclipse and check `git status` from terminal.